# How to create a sub-associative object from a list of array keys in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, associative-array

I have an object from user input. The keys to that object are separated by commas, and I just want to separate those keys and make the keys of the object.

The `key_array` below is dynamic from user input, generates a different array each time, below I give you an example.
I have shown the object in my code which you can see below. you can also see the output by running that code.

```js
var main_array = {};
var key_array = {
    'user,name' : 'user name',
    'user,email' : 'Email address',
    'order,id' : 123456,
    'order,qty' : 2,
    'order,total' : 300,
    'order,product,0,name' : "product1",
    'order,product,0,qty' : 1,
    'order,product,0,price' : 100,
    'order,product,1,name' : "product2",
    'order,product,1,qty' : 1,
    'order,product,1,price' : 200,
};

for (keys in key_array){
    var value = key_array[keys];

    // What do I do here to get the output I want?
    main_array['[' + keys.split(",").join('][')+ ']'] = value;
}
console.log(main_array);
```

Running the code above will give you the following output which is incorrect. And the output I don't want.

```json
{
    [order][id]: 123456,
    [order][product][0][name]: "product1",
    [order][product][0][price]: 100,
    [order][product][0][qty]: 1,
    [order][product][1][name]: "product2",
    [order][product][1][price]: 200,
    [order][product][1][qty]: 1,
    [order][qty]: 2,
    [order][total]: 300,
    [user][email]: "Email address",
    [user][name]: "user name"
}
```

I want an output like JSON below, so please tell me how to do it.

```json
{
    "user":{
        "email" : "Email address",
        "name"  : "user name"
    },
    "order":{
        "id"    : 123456,
        "qty"   : 2,
        "total" : 300,
        "product":[
            {
                "name"  : "product1",
                "price" : 100,
                "qty"   : 1
            },{
                "name"  : "product2",
                "price" : 200,
                "qty"   : 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Note: Please do not use `eval`, as using `eval` in this way is terribly unreliable, bad work and unsafe. Because I get all my data from user input, the likelihood of abuse can increase.

Comment: Iterate over the split result and build the object accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the objects and keys required from the string dynamically, take each key and split it to an array using `split(',')`. Using each item in the array create the structure required. Assuming if a key is a number, then it's parent must be an array.

```js
Object.keys(key_array).forEach(key => {
    const path = key.split(',');
    let current = main_array;

    for (let i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
        if (!current[path[i]]) {
            current[path[i]] = path[i + 1] && !isNaN(path[i + 1]) ? [] : {};
        }
        current = current[path[i]];
    }
    current[path.pop()] = key_array[key];
});

console.log(main_array); // Desired result
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `Object.entries` to go over key and values of object.
2. Split the `key` by `,` separator and then build the object.
3. While building object, make sure to merge the keys and values using `mergeTo` method.
4. Then convert the objects which has the numerical keys then convert to object using `convertObjsToArray` method.

```js
var key_array = {
  "user,name": "user name",
  "user,email": "Email address",
  "order,id": 123456,
  "order,qty": 2,
  "order,total": 300,
  "order,product,0,name": "product1",
  "order,product,0,qty": 1,
  "order,product,0,price": 100,
  "order,product,1,name": "product2",
  "order,product,1,qty": 1,
  "order,product,1,price": 200
};

const mergeTo = (target, obj) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && !Array.isArray(value)) {
      if (!target[key]) {
        target[key] = {};
      }
      mergeTo(target[key], obj[key]);
    } else {
      target[key] = value;
    }
  });
};

const convertObjsToArray = obj => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      if (Object.keys(value).every(num => Number.isInteger(Number(num)))) {
        obj[key] = Object.values(value);
      } else {
        convertObjsToArray(obj[key]);
      }
    }
  });
};

const res = {};
Object.entries(key_array).map(([key, value]) => {
  const keys = key.split(",");
  let curr = { [keys.pop()]: value };
  while (keys.length > 0) {
    curr = { [keys.pop()]: curr };
  }
  mergeTo(res, curr);
});
convertObjsToArray(res);

console.log(res);
```